# Best way to read in a .tab file in iOS when there are nulls in the file

Tags: ios, objective-c, tabs, nsstring, nsdata

So I'm trying to read in [this file](https://www.caa.govt.nz/fulltext/Pubdocs/AircraftRegisterExport.tab) but when I open it in sumblime I see a bunch of NUL characters. I don't know too much about encoding, but when I try read it in with

`NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                                  encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                                     error:&error];`

It only reads up to the first NUL, which, from what I remember from my C days, is probably expected behaviour). When I try UTF8 encoding with the above call, I get back nil.

Im thinking maybe read it in a different way? With NSData or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

I just looked at it in a file editor and it looks like it's in ISO Latin 1. try using NSISOLatin1StringEncoding.